# Volume of trade covered by regional trade agreements

Tags: international-trade

Is anyone aware of statistics about the total volume of trade that happens under regional trade agreements (RTAs)? It's easy to find figures for [the number of agreements](https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/region_e/regfac_e.htm), but not so easy for their cumulative impact.

Comment: For which period are you looking for? For recent years you can compute them based on trade data and information on RTAs.

Comment: @emeryville: I'm not sure it's that simple because RTAs are do not necessarily cover all commerce between countries. So even if I know X exports to Y $E in total, and I know X and Y are part of a RTA, the RTA may exclude (or specifically only include) certain products. I think agricultural products are commonly excluded in most RTAs, for example.

Comment: Nothing prevents you using disaggregated trade data

Comment: @emeryville You might be surprised at how much international trade that would qualify to use an RTA, doesn't.  Also the complexity of mapping bilateral trade flows to 6- or 8-digit HS lines for each of the hundreds of RTAs in effect is... left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called "utilization rate" and I believe a government agency in most countries should have this information. Here's one example: https://english.bdi.eu/article/news/the-preference-utilization-rate-of-eu-free-trade-agreements/